# Bootstrap style modal without using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I want to use bootstrap modal in my project however when I load bootstrap stylesheets it brakes my website as it seems to be overwriting alot of my CSS.

Does anyone know Bootstrap style script that I could use without loading whole bootstrap just for using modal feature ? Or is there any other way i can use bootstraps modal without braking my CSS. Cheers

PS. Yes, I tried loading bootstrap before my CSS stylesheets, it still overwrites my CSS.

Comment: You can avoid the bootstrap.css assets and apply the custom styles to the modal.  This approach is the tough one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can customize your css for bootstrap.

Use this link for doing that: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

[image]

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thats what I was looking for! Thank you :) however i only choosed modal to be in my custom bootstrap, reseted everything else for typography etc. and it still affected my text (all h1,h2,h3's and paragraphs)

Comment: If only header style are being affected, override those styles by yours header styles using !important flag.  I’m suggesting this because the only affected styles are the header ones.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent CSS to be overwritten, use the !important flag:

```css
p {
  color: blue !important;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>my stuff</p>
```

Comment: It's an alternative, however, that leads to doing that for the entire project and is prone to make wrong stuff.  Further, every new style will need a treatment to follow the desired style.

Comment: yeah, it's not the solution for his specific problem. Might be helpful though.